# AWS sam build not building lambda functions

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-sam

I'm new to building with AWS SAM. When I execute `sam build` it shows build succeeded but I don't see my function in the build directory.
This is my directory structure

```
Folder PATH listing for volume Code
Volume serial number is B243-6647
D:.
ª   .gitignore
ª   template.yaml
ª   tree.txt
ª   
+---.aws-sam
ª   ª   build.toml
ª   ª   
ª   +---build
ª           template.yaml
ª           
+---events
ª       testHelloWorld.json
ª       
+---lambdas
ª   +---HelloWorld
ª           index.py
ª           __init__.py
ª
```

This is the contents of the `template.yaml`

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Globals:
  Function:
    Runtime: python3.9
    Handler: index.handler

Resources:
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Properties:
      Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
      CodeUri: lambdas/HelloWorld/

    Policies:
      - AWSLambdaExecute
      - Version: '2012-10-17'
```

And this is `lambdas/HelloWorld/index.py`

```
import json

def handler(event, context):
  return json.dumps(event, indent=2)
```

This is the state of the build folder after `sam build`

```
Folder PATH listing for volume Code
Volume serial number is B243-6647
D:\WEB\URLSHORTENER\.AWS-SAM
│   build.toml
│
└───build
        template.yaml
```

Can someone please help me in figuring out why the functions are not available?

Comment: i would recommend you look into CDK or serverless.yaml instead

Comment: @JoranBeasley thanks any specific reason to avoid sam?

Comment: its overly compicated and convoluted imho ...those other tools end up generating sam under the hood

Answer (score 0):

I was *almost* doing everything right. Just needed to add `Type` outside `Properties` :/
Updated `template.yaml`

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: Url Shortener

Globals:
  Function:
    Handler: index.handler
    Runtime: python3.9

Resources:
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: lambdas/HelloWorld/
    Policies:
      - AWSLambdaExecute
      - Version: '2012-10-17'
```